# How to dynamically calculate position and place a header to group of html table columns using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to place a label which will act as a header to a group of columns in a table ,  the label should begin at the 7th column and end of the 12th column ,covering the columns from 7-12..Could anyone please tell how I can do this with jQuery ?

Comment: Why do you need jQuery for this? You can simply structure the table to have a particular column with colspan of 6, starting from 7th column. This would be the first row of your table.

Comment: thtz because my datatable is generated via jquery datatables plugin

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the comment, you don't need to use javascript at all:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=6 style="visibility:hidden"> </th> <!-- 1..6 -->
    <th colspan=6> header for 7-12 </th> <!-- 7..12 -->
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

---

You can append the same structure dynamically as well, should you need to; here's one way:

```
$("#my-table").prepend(
  $("<tr>").append(
    $("<td>",{colspan:6})
      .css({visibility:"hidden"})
  ).append(
    $("<td>",{colspan:6})
      .text("header for 7-12")
  )
)
```

---

If you don't want to use colspan, you'll have to position the header manually; here's a sketch (untested):

```
var header = $("<div>")
  .css({position:"relative", top:0})
    //note the use of 'relative' to allocate space
  .text("header for 7-12");
var table = $("#my-table");
table.prepend(header.wrap("<tr><td/></tr>"));

(function recalculate(){
   header.css({
     left:$("td:nth-child(6)",table).offset().left - table.offset().left,
     width: table.width() - $("td:nth-child(6)",table).offset().left
       //assuming there's no 13th column
   })
})(); //invoke now

$(window).on("resize", recalculate);
table.on("my-data-change", recalculate);
  //when you change the table, do $("#my-table").trigger("my-data-change")
```